# How to fix local infeasibility in IPOPT with Python Gekko?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, ipopt, gekko

I get a local infeasibility error in IPOPT (v3.12.10).

```
Converged to a point of local infeasibility. Problem may be infeasible.
```

I also tried it with the APOPT solver using `m.options.SOLVER=1` and get a similar error.

```
No feasible solution
```

There are multiple feasible solutions to this problem with two equations and three variables. Solutions to this problem are where the plane intersects the sphere.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x=m.Var(); y=m.Var(); z=m.Var()
m.Equations([x**2+y**2+z**2==1,x+z==y])
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # APOPT=1, IPOPT=3
m.solve(debug=0) # debug=0 doesn't stop when unsuccessful
print('Solution 1')
print(x.value[0],y.value[0],z.value[0])
```

When I add an objective function to maximize `z` then IPOPT converges to a solution.

```py
# add objective
m.Obj(-z) # maximize z
m.solve()
print('Solution 2')
print(x.value[0],y.value[0],z.value[0])
```

How can I avoid a failed solution without adding an objective function?

Answer (score 4):

The starting point at `x=0`, `y=0`, and `z=0` needs a different initial guess to converge to a solution.

```py
x=m.Var(0.01); y=m.Var(); z=m.Var()
```

Because many solutions exist, a different solution will be obtained with different initial guess values. The objective function that you tried `m.Obj(-z)` improves convergence but also makes the solution unique.

All of the solution options in GEKKO are gradient-based nonlinear programming solvers and include APOPT, BPOPT, IPOPT, and others. All of these solvers produce solutions that are only guaranteed to be a local minimum or maximum. They all use the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker) to determine when an optimal solution is found. By starting at `x=0`, `y=0`, and `z=0`, the second KKT condition (No Feasible Descent) is satisfied but the first condition is not satisfied (Feasible Constraints). This leads to the error that you observed with the solver reporting a local infeasibility. The point is also called a stationary point where the function's derivative is zero.